# Which OpAmp supports voltage supply greater than + - 36V

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

I'm looking OpAmp which could be powered from dual power supply greater than  + - 36V. 
Current transformer provides 36,9V. And LM358 on a single supply could work up to 36V. I'm looking something what could be work on dual supply up to 40V.
Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Try searching [Apex](https://www.apexanalog.com/) they have pretty large range of HV op-amp, expensive thouh.

Comment: Linear has several listed [**here**](http://www.linear.com/parametric/Operational_Amplifiers_(Op_Amps)#!1004_>=80!gbw_!vsmax_80!sr_!ismax_!vos_!enoise_!vosdrift_!lfnoise_!ibias_!inoise_).

Comment: Yeah I've used the linear LT6090

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a conventional current transformer and has an internal burden then applying an extra external burden resistor will lower the output voltage and give you more options on the choice of op-amp. Alternatively just use a potential divider to reduce the voltage to a more acceptable level.

PS asking for device recommendations is the quickest way to get a question closed. read the rules: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thank you for a tip, I'll keep it in mind. I was just struggling to solve this step.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother trying to find a +/- 40V op amp, just add a high voltage output stage to your LM358.

[image]

See page 8 http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa600b/snoa600b.pdf

Edit:

Having said that I did find this: The LM143 which runs up to +/- 40V

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva516/snva516.pdf

Comment: This will make circuit much complex just because of this 1V. But it is a solution. 
Thank you

Comment: Using a dual supply you only get +/- 16V (32 V max) on an lm358 so it not just a 1V difference. Your +/- 40V target means you'll need something capable of handling 80V. If you search around you might be able to find a simpler design for the output stage or even an IC with it all built in.

Comment: FYI: the particular circuit you show is from National's AN-272. The link to that application note in the how-to wiki is dead but AN-272 can be found at http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa600b/snoa600b.pdf. The circuit is explained on pp. 7-9 (section 5: +/-120V Swing Booster).

Comment: Yes, I was confused and thought that it was 36V.
Basically I need one op amp to increase  5 to 36 range and other to invert -5 to positive 36V. So supplying ground to VCC and -30 to Vee. works as well. The only one problem how to get 40V range in inexpensive way. :)
But I found some solutions already to try and suggestions here needs to be tested as well.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the LTC6090, which accomodates a supply voltage of up to 140V (+/- 70V) with rail to rail output swing and generally reasonable specifications all around:

http://www.linear.com/product/LTC6090

Comment: This one good. But very expensive 5$ for one.